# VHDL Shift right register issues

Tags: vhdl, shift

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to implement in VHDL a shift register for a divisor component. The shift register has to take a 15 bit input and shift it to the right every clock cycle, while chaining a '0' on the most significant bit.
I,ve wrote this code

---

------- SHIFT RIGHT ----------------------------------

```
>  library IEEE; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; use ieee.numeric_std.all;
> 
> entity shift_right is port(   in_shift_right: in std_logic_vector(14
> downto 0);
>       clk_shift_right, rst_shift_right : in std_logic;
>       out_shift_right : out std_logic_vector (14 downto 0) ); end shift_right;
> 
> architecture behavioral of shift_right is begin  
> process(clk_shift_right, rst_shift_right, in_shift_right )   variable
> tmp : std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);    begin
>     if rising_edge (clk_shift_right) then     elsif rst_shift_right = '1' then  
>       tmp := (others => '0');
>     elsif rising_edge(clk_shift_right) then 
>       tmp:='0'&in_shift_right(14 downto 1);
>           end if;
>            out_shift_right<=tmp;   end process;    end behavioral;
```

This is the result on the waveform tested with Quartus' grafic tool:

[image]

This in not what i'm looking for, in fact in only works for the first clock cycle.
Although i've found the following code online

```
>      library IEEE;
>     use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
>     
>     entity shift is
>     port(
>           clk:in std_logic;
>           rst:in std_logic;
>           sin:in std_logic;
>           pin:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
>           mode:in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
>           sout:out std_logic;
>           pout:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
>           );
>     end shift;
>     
>     
>     architecture Behavioral of shift is
>     signal temp:std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
>     
>     
>     begin
>         process(rst,clk,sin,mode,pin)
>           
>           begin
>           
>           if rst='1' then
>           sout<='0';
>           pout<="00000000";
>           temp<="00000000";
>           
>           
>           elsif(clk'event and clk='1')then
>           
>             case mode is
>             --SISO
>             when "00"=>
>             temp(6 downto 0)<= temp(7 downto 1);
>             temp(7)<=sin;
>             sout<=temp(0);
>             
>             --SIPO
>             when"01"=>
>             temp(6 downto 0)<= temp(7 downto 1);
>             temp(7)<=sin;
>             pout<=temp;
>           
>             --PIPO
>             when"10"=>
>             temp<=pin;
>             pout<=temp;
>            
>              
>             when others=>
>             null;
>             
>             end case;
>             
>           end if; 
>              
>           end process;
>           
>     end Behavioral;
```

IT actually works as i want, but, as you can see from the waveform, it only works when the mode chosen on "case" it's '01', but only if this comes after the '10' mode.
I also can't understand why it works only after a clock cycle delay, that I highlighted in the picture:

[image: https://ibb.co/m4W738v]

Really thank to anyone could help me

Comment: Your code is very messy. I think if you just tidy up the indentation you will start to see some problems immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you tidy up the indentation of your code, I think you will start to see some problems immediately. For example, think about what this code will do:

```
if rising_edge (clk_shift_right) then

elsif rst_shift_right = '1' then  
    tmp := (others => '0');
elsif rising_edge(clk_shift_right) then
    ...
```

The contents of the final `elsif` can never be reached.

A second comment is that you have put `rst` and `in_shift_right` in the sensitivity list. Do you want a synchronous or asynchronous reset? If synchronous, then `rst` doesn't need to be in the sensitivity list. Either way, I don't see any reason to put `in_shift_right` in the sensitivity list.

A third comment is that your use of a `variable` (`tmp`) is potentially worrying. Your usage is perfectly valid and syntactically correct, but seems a very strange choice in this context. If this is a deliberate stylistic choice, then that's fine. However, if you just don't understand the differences between a `signal` and a `variable`, then I recommend devoting a little time to that. Remember, this is not software; you are describing hardware.

A fourth comment is that your assignment `tmp:='0'&in_shift_right(14 downto 1);` **always** uses the upper 14 bits of the input `in_shift_right`. This is clearly not what you want to do (you want to keep shifting right). Try to think about what kind of hardware would be needed to do this.

You already include the `ieee.numeric_std` library, so there is actually a `shift_right` function you can use directly. You don't describe exactly what you want your block to do, but I guess it is something like this (assuming asynchronous reset):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity right_shifter is
generic (
    DATA_BITS       : positive := 15
);
port (
    clk             : in std_logic;
    rst             : in std_logic;
    -- Input
    in_valid        : in std_logic;
    in_data         : in std_logic_vector(DATA_BITS-1 downto 0);
    -- Control
    shift_enable    : in std_logic;
    -- Output
    out_data        : out std_logic_vector(DATA_BITS-1 downto 0)
);
end right_shifter;

architecture rtl of right_shifter is

    signal data     : unsigned(DATA_BITS-1 downto 0);

begin

    process(clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            -- Reset
            data <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if in_valid = '1' then
                -- Load new input
                data <= unsigned(in_data);
            elsif shift_enable = '1' then
                -- Shift right
                data <= shift_right(data, 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    out_data <= std_logic_vector(data);

end rtl;
```

Or, with a synchronous reset:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity right_shifter is
generic (
    DATA_BITS       : positive := 15
);
port (
    clk             : in std_logic;
    rst             : in std_logic;
    -- Input
    in_valid        : in std_logic;
    in_data         : in std_logic_vector(DATA_BITS-1 downto 0);
    -- Control
    shift_enable    : in std_logic;
    -- Output
    out_data        : out std_logic_vector(DATA_BITS-1 downto 0)
);
end right_shifter;

architecture rtl of right_shifter is

    signal data     : unsigned(DATA_BITS-1 downto 0);

begin

    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst = '1' then
                -- Reset
                data <= (others => '0');
            elsif in_valid = '1' then
                -- Load new input
                data <= unsigned(in_data);
            elsif shift_enable = '1' then
                -- Shift right
                data <= shift_right(data, 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    out_data <= std_logic_vector(data);

end rtl;
```